# How to customize regex validation messages in backoffice?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Is it possible to replace the "Value is invalid, it does not match the correct pattern" with customized message?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change this message to a custom one without writing custom code or changing the language files.

What you can do however to make the field more user friendly, is adding a description to the field that explains the expected formatting of the field.